# Strange terraform state behaviour in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We keep our terraform state in S3. Here is a use case:
I create a new security group rule and perform a `terraform apply`. The security group rule is created.
Now when I download the terraform state file using `terraform state pull` I don't see this security group rule in the file, while it does exist in AWS.

Now when I reapply the same stack there is NO change (as expected), but when I pull the state again I finally see the new security group rule in the state file.

How can this be explained?

Below is added to the tf state after applying a second time:

```
        "description": "HTTPS to zzz",  
        "from_port": 443,   
        "ipv6_cidr_blocks": [], 
        "prefix_list_ids": [],  
        "protocol": "tcp",  
        "security_groups": [    
          "xxx/yyy" 
        ],  
        "self": false,  
        "to_port": xxx  
      },    
      { 
        "cidr_blocks": [],
```

Comment: Can you specify your terraform and aws provider versions?

Comment: Maybe because of eventual consistency in S3?

Comment: Can you provide any reproducible example TF code that can be independently run to test this behavior?

Comment: it's a big stack so I'm not sure if I can just add en example. But in the last case it was just by adding a security group rule

Comment: @DenCowboy Can you explain again what did you do? `terraform state pull` should not add SG to your local state file. It only outputs remote state to stdout. To actually save it, you have to do `terraform state pull > terraform.tfstate`. So I'm not sure what you did exactly that it got saved. Can you double check?

Comment: @Marcin I did indeed: terraform state pull > terraform.tfstate. So first an apply which was fine (rule was added), then a state pull (rule was not there), again an apply (no change), new state pull (to a file) and the rule was there. I've had it multiple times already.

Comment: So I think it's how it should be. Pull by itself does not save the state. Maybe I misunderstand your issue, but for me it behaves as expected.

Comment: @Marcin for me it seems that the state is not saved after the first apply (although it knows that the rule is created, it is not in the state file, after a second apply it is in the state file.

Comment: This is not how it should work. Maybe you can update your question with sample TF code (not real one, but something short that can be used to reproduce your setup), and explain in steps what do you do, providing exact commands that you are using.